# HPE DL360 Gen10 with Samsung 990 PRO NVMe - Really poor performance

Tags: linux, ssd, nvme, hpe

Yesterday, I installed a Samsung 990 Pro NVMe in my HPE DL360 Gen10 using a Glotrends PA09-HS M.2 PCIe 4.0 NVMe X4 adapter. Unfortunately, it's not performing as expected. I'm only achieving a write speed of 800MB/s, which is quite poor considering the NVMe's specifications.

I am aware that the HPE DL360 Gen10 supports only PCIe 3.0, but this adapter is backward compatible, and even on PCIe 3.0, I should see write speeds of up to 4GB/s.

I've experimented with the BIOS settings, but it didn't help. I tested the write speed on all PCIe resource padding settings (normal, medium, high), then checked the PCIe link speed, which was set to auto. In the dropdown menu, I only had the option to select 1.0 and 2.0 generations - there was nothing regarding 3.0.

I have two CPUs inside this server - Intel Silver 4114, which support PCIe 3.0.

The adapter with the NVMe is in slot 2 (port x8) on the HP Riser Card 869432-001.

I'm using Debian 12 to test the speed.

Does anyone know what else I can do to resolve this issue and achieve at least 2GB/s write speed?

Comment: How did you test perfromance? Did you use fio?

Comment: HP is somewhat known for semi proprietary hardware. I would at least try it with a different controller. The $10 controller is easily swapped.

Comment: @batistuta09 I did dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test1.img bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync and also tried to change oflag to direct.

Comment: @GregAskew I've ordered two more adapters, the ICY BOX IB-PCI215M2-HSL and the SABRENT EC-PCIE. Their bandwidth is similar to that of the Glotrends, at around 700-800MB/s.